# Streaming a WAV file. (NOT recording)

Tags: javascript, audio, wav

I'm trying to play a .wav as background music (It's match ambience) but I'm having problems getting it to stream, it's 20meg so I don't really want to make people wait for it to download... could be waiting 30seconds!

I had it working fine in IE but FF doesn't seem to like any code that works in IE :)

I was using an object to hold the sound which worked in IE. I also had some javascript fading the sound in and out when I wanted to.

Could anyone please provide me with a code snipplet for cross browser compatability for playing wav files without the need of additional plugins (if possible) and without using jquery or prototype or anything similar.

Comment: wav is a container format. Think of it as a grocery bag - it could hold tonight's supper, or your cat's last week's worth of crap from the litter box. Whether whatever audio format is inside your wav is amenable to streaming depends entirely on what codec was used to create the wav in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

But you should compress the [wav file to mp3](https://www.google.com/search?q=wav%20to%20mp3). You can see a live demo [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio).

Comment: Great for browsers that know HTML5.

Comment: Many thanks, this works great (had to use wav instead of ogg though)... my server doesn't like ogg files for some reason. How would I change that? I use IIS7. thanks

Comment: What do you mean with doesn't like?

Comment: if i put an ogg file there, it doesn't work... so i have to use wav and mp3 now.